# Rails 5 - Collection caching not refreshing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I think I must be missing something here on how **[Collection caching - 1.3.1](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching)** works. When I add the `cached: true` attribute to the render it **will not** refresh the cache when a model changes. However, without this attribute it will work as expected.

attending.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'attending_item', collection: @attendees, locals: {reserved: true}, cached: true %>
```

_item_attending.html.erb

```
<% cache([attendee.user, attendee, reserved]) do %>
  <li class="attendee_id_<%= attendee.id %> <%= reserved ? 'reserved' : 'confirmed' %>">
  <%= image_tag(attendee.user.profile.avatar_url(:avatar), size: '25x25') %>
  <%= attendee.user.full_name %>
 </li>
<% end %>
```

The **user** model will get updated via a `touch: true` on the Profile model, so when they update there avatar for example:

```
belongs_to :user, touch: true
```

Can someone explain to me what I am missing or not understanding how a **Collection cache** works, maybe it's a bug in **Rails**?

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game here, but I don't think you cache is expiring because it is dependent on the user and reserved values.

Looking at the better documentation of the multi_fetch_fragments [gem](https://github.com/n8/multi_fetch_fragments#multi-fetch-fragments) which was merged into Rails to make this possible adds some clues.

I think you want to change your `cache: true` to `cache: Proc.new { |attendee| [attendee, user, reserved] }` to take into account the change there.

Additionally, I believe you'd want to remove the `cache` blocks within the `_item_attending.html.erb` file as the partial is automatically cached.